# listbox items disappearing / not displaying when inserting

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, telerik

I'm creating a data transfer control between 2 listboxes.
I have items displaying in both boxes, with the text and property values holding data.
When I transfer from one to the other though, I can access the transferred item (using debug) and see the text property (not the value property), but it's not displaying in the listbox that I sent it to. 
I've even tried refreshing the object, but no luck.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
private void btnToLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListDataItem item = new Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListDataItem(lstRight.SelectedItem.DisplayValue.ToString(), lstRight.SelectedItem.Value);
            lstLeft.Items.Add(item);
            lstRight.Items.RemoveAt(lstRight.SelectedItem.RowIndex);
            lstLeft.Refresh();
            lstRight.Refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use for a similar situation.

```
private void btnToLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (lstRight.Items.Count == 0) { return; }
      if (lstRight.SelectedItem == null) { return; }

      RadListDataItem item = lstRight.SelectedItem;
      lstRight.Items.Remove(item);
      lstLeft.Items.Add(item);
}
```

You could make this a little more generic like this.

```
private void MoveToTargetListBox(RadListControl sourceListBox, RadListControl targetListBox)
{
  try
  {
    if (sourceListBox.Items.Count == 0) { return; }
    if (sourceListBox.SelectedItem == null) { return; }

    RadListDataItem item = sourceListBox.SelectedItem;
    sourceListBox.Items.Remove(item);
    targetListBox.Items.Add(item);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //handle Exception
  }
}

private void btnToLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MoveToTargetListBox(lstRight, lstLeft);
}

private void btnToRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MoveToTargetListBox(lstLeft, lstRight);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this almost works for me - when I move the item over though, the value is lost. .. . any idea how I can get it to stay/persist?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. . . I referenced the lstRight.SelectedItem.DisplayValue.ToString() instead of the text value - lstRight.SelectedItem.Text

Seems to work now. .. .  !